# Matomo - get users and last visit

Tags: matomo

I am struggling finding the good params for the [Reporting API from Matomo](https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/reporting-api) to get a list of the userIds and their last visit.
The method `UserId.getUsers` give us all the users with these params:

```
label: 
nb_visits: 
nb_actions: 
max_actions: 
sum_visit_length: 
bounce_count: 
nb_visits_converted: 
sum_daily_nb_uniq_visitors: 
sum_daily_nb_users: 
idvisitor: 
segment:
```

but not the last visit timestamp. And I can't find the good method and params to get what I am looking for.

Moreover, even with one `userId`, I can't find the proper method/params to get the last visit for this userId...

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

Using our HTTP API you can export all your individual users data and all users actions (visits, pages, clicks, events, downloads, custom dimensions, user location, user information, and more). The API used to export all your Raw data is called Live.getLastVisitsDetails and lets you export all the user and clickstream data for a given website and a given date. Optionally a Custom Segment when you need to export specific segment of users). For example if you wanted to export the full dataset for yesterday, you would use the following API call:

https://demo.matomo.org/?module=API&method=Live.getLastVisitsDetails&idSite=62&period=day&date=yesterday&format=xml&token_auth=anonymous&filter_limit=100

Learn more: https://matomo.org/faq/how-to/faq_24536/